# Outlook 2013 HTML Signature with Image Background

Tags: html, outlook, background-image, outlook-2013

I have found another thread ([Outlook 2013 background image broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613230/outlook-2013-background-image-broken)) however I can't comment as I am a new user of Stack Overflow. Here's my code:

```
<table width="695" height="194" border="0" cellpadding="0" style="background-image:url('http://champ.website-admin.net/files/2014/12/email.jpg'); padding:24px;">
 <tbody>
<tr>
  <td><h3>Emma Woolward</h3></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><p><a href="mailto:operations@champresources.com.au">operations@champresources.com.au</a></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><p>1300 GO CHAMP</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><p>P: 1300 462 426</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><a href="www.champresources.com.au"><p>www.champresources.com.au</p></a></td>
</tr>
 <tr>
  <td><a href="https://www.facebook.com/champresources?fref=ts"><img src="http://champ.website-admin.net/files/2014/12/facebook.png" style="width:100px;height:33px; float: left;"></a><img src="http://champ.website-admin.net/files/2014/12/zeroharm.png" style="float:left; margin-left:5px;"></td>
</tr>
```

Background image is not appearing.  The response to the similar thread suggests to use a multipart e-mail and they offered a code example:

```
--==boundary-1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Base: http://test.endlesspeak.cz

<td background="cid:bg-deepak.jpg">
--==boundary-1
Content-type: image/jpg; name="bg-deepak.jpg"
Content-ID: <bg-deepak.jpg>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="bg-deepak.gif"
```

I am wondering where this example code is best to go within the head?

Or does anybody else have any other thoughts on why the background image disappears when it goes into outlook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that Outlook uses Word to render HTML, not IE. Don't know if Word supports background images for tables, AFAIK it does not support background images for the  tag.

Comment: Thanks after some more research last night I realised that using the background image was more pain than its worth and changed the style of that cell to a block colour. This fixed my issue.